# angular.fromJson(data.Body) vs JSON.parse(data.Body)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I have use JSON.parse(data.Body) it give me the correct result, which is an object.

Since I do npm run lint, it gives me error: 'You should use the angular.fromJson methof instead of JSON.parse

this is my code: `this.$log.log(angular.fromJson(data.Body), JSON.parse(data.Body));`

[image]

I can't understand what is the first output, Uint8Array?

**What should I do to get the same results?** I don't need the unsigned intergers....
The data.Body is just array of integers, but when I did JSON.parse, it's an Object
[image]

**WHERE IS MY OBJECT?????!**

Comment: `UInt8Arrays` are arrays of unsigned 8-bit integers - see [Javascript typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Comment: show us what is `data.Body`. angular.fromJSON is just a wrapper around JSON.parse() that checks if the argument is string

Comment: @Maximus I have updated

Comment: `JSON.parse([1,2,3])` produces `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`, so `data.Body` it seems can't be array of integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there is a good example:

var strJSON= '
{"name":"mital",
"age":25,
"address":"India"
}';

document.write(angular.fromJson(strJSON));  
document.write("");

Answer (score 1):

There is one more solution please add angular.toJson instead of angular.fromJson.
Here is my example:`var jsonData={ 
     "links":[
         {country: "india", state: "gujarat"}
]
document.write(angular.toJson(jsonData))`